# Adjust position of Arabic text on an image

Tags: php, image, gd

Hello guys I am new here and my English is bad, sorry for that.

I have a problem with `imagettfstring` start position, Arabic is from right to left so i have problem in keeping Arabic at custom position, for example 50px away from right.

Trying to show what I mean with image:
[image]

I want the red text in the bottom to start from the right if that is possible, the text is starting from left to right, is there a way to stick the black line at the white line?
and I want when the text get bigger to go with the brown arrow direction

The code I am using:

```
<?php
    require_once("image.php");
    $image = new image;
    if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
        $image -> createFromFile(1, "gbg.png");
        $c = $image -> arabttfBox(45, 0, "andlso.ttf", $_REQUEST["name"]);
        $image -> arabttfString(1, $c[0], "andlso.ttf", 45, "#F00", 0, 0 , 100);
        $image -> arabttfString(1, $_REQUEST["name"], "andlso.ttf", 45, "#F00",
                                0, 0 , 520);
        $image -> display(1, "png");
    } else {
        $image -> create("error", 400, 100, "#333");
        $image -> border("error", "#000", "3");
        $image -> string("error", "Post a name", 5, "#F00", 10, 10, true, true);
        $image -> display("error", "png");
    }
?>
```

The image:
[image]

the Arabic text if you want to copy:

> سمر علي

If you want me to upload the font, tell me.

After some thinking I have solved it:

```
list($IW, $IH) = $this -> dimensions($ID);
list($FW, $FH) = $this -> arabttfBox($Size, $Angle, $Font, fagd($string));
return imagettftext($this -> image[$ID], $Size, $Angle, $IW-$FW-$X, $Y,
                    imagecolorallocate($this -> image[$ID], $R, $G, $B),
                    $Font, fagd($string));
```

Comment: will you please Add some code ?

Comment: i have solved it ^^ thanks anyway

Comment: ohh sorry for late comment, great will you pls add this into your answer so some one can have some problem so it will useful to thme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution :

```
list($IW, $IH) = $this -> dimensions($ID);
list($FW, $FH) = $this -> arabttfBox($Size, $Angle, $Font, fagd($string));
return imagettftext($this -> image[$ID], $Size, $Angle, $IW-$FW-$X, $Y,
                    imagecolorallocate($this -> image[$ID], $R, $G, $B),
                    $Font, fagd($string));
```

[image]